# Detecting text with Google Vision API ignores some characters

Tags: google-api, ocr, text-recognition

I'm using Google Vision API to recognize text from an image. It works usually fine but if the text contains closing curly braces `}` it is almost always ignored. There is no problem with the opening curly braces `{` on the same image.

For example the following input (in image format):

```
{
    line1 
    {
        line2
    }
    line3
}
line4
```

Results the following:

```
{
    line1 
    {
        line2
    line3
line4
```

I'm using `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`

Any idea?

Comment: have you solved?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: btw do you know how to set a block to an image and only extract the text that inside in the block only with this api?